# Display special characters using entity or hex values

Tags: java, unicode, utf-8

I am trying to display ŵ through my jsf page but unable to do so. Basically the text with special characters is read from properties file , but on my application screen it becomes something else . I did try to use entity values but not succeeding for example if original text is :

ŵyhsne klqdw dwql
then after replacing with with entity or hexvalues:
**&wcirc ;**yhsne klqdw dwql  but in my page it displays as it is

Comment: You should take some more effort to explain what it is your problem, to structure and format better your question, and explicitly write what did you tried. `&wcirc;` is used on web and ev. on some xml files. Are you doing a web application? Where is it your string? In code? in a file that you read? in a resource file?

Answer (score 0):

I can just guess your question. Please edit it and improve it.

If you are displaying in web, you should use `&wcirc;` (note: without spaces), but this also requires a fonts on client site that support such character.

If the string is in your code: replace the character with `\u0175`.

But probably the best way it is to use just `ŵ` either in code on in web, or on any file, and you should assure that such files (or sources) are interpreted ad UTF-8, and you deliver pages are UTF-8. If you are not using UTF-8, just check in similar way, that you are using consistently the correct encoding.

And sending a character doesn't mean it could be displayed. There is always the possibility that a font will not have all *special" characters in it.